# Windows 10 Title bar not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, directx, windows-10

I have a Windows Store app that works great on Windows 8.  I am trying to update it to deal with the new Windows 10 quirks, etc. but when I run the application on a windows 10 machine, the title bar (with the max, min, and close buttons) is completely unresponsive.  This means that I can't close the app, or move it, or anything having to do with the title bar.  I can resize the window, but nothing having to do with the title bar is working...

For further reference, this is a Direct3d app written in C++.  No XAML or anything, all DirectX.

**UPDATE:**
Using the project template (VS2013) for Univeral DirectX App creates an application that has the exact same problem.  Is this a known issue or something?

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of banging around, I have discovered that the source of the problem seems to be related to the debugger (Visual Studio Express 2013).  If I run the application outside of the debugger, the title bar / window does exactly what it is supposed to do.  Go figure.